# DRF and PostgreSQL: ArrayField is returned as an array of chars

Tags: django, postgresql, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a Contact model with a field like this:

```
#models.py

address = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True), default=list)
```

This stores an array of email addresses. I'm creating an api and wanted this to be returned as an array of email addresses as strings but I get an array of chars instead (as in the screenshot). Can someone hint me what to do?

My serializer:

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = '__all__'
```

Output:
[image: output]

EDIT:
Example address from a db record:
[image]

EDIT 2:
This is how the value looked like in pandas DataFrame just before being stored in db:
[image]

Comment: You need to submit it in a list, so `address = ['foo@bar.com']`, not `address={foo@bar.com'}`, or `address='foo@bar.com'` or `address='{foo@bar.com}'`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  Submit as in where? The only thing I'm doing is the GET request on an existing db

Comment: it looks like you stored the email addresses in the wrong way then in the database. Not as a list of strings, but as some sort of string, and then it will call `list` over it.

Comment: how did you "populate" the database in the first place?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I edited the initial post with an example value of address of record in a db. I populated it with a pre-prepared script that made a use of pandas etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I also provided a screen shot with this value from when it was inside a DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [ListField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield)?

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = '__all__'

    address = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField())
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem, you can try to drop the database. Sometimes, migration won't cut it. @WillemVanOnsem is right, the ArrayField was saved as a string instead of an array, that's why it printed out as a list of chars